# Full Calendar - How to add leading zeros to the days in Month View of Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add leading Zeros to these single digit days in FullCalendar month view.

[image]

What I want is :

[image]

Means, 3 as 03, 4 as 04 and so on..

Comment: If you are not ok with @ADyson solution you can still change the source code. Here is the place https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/7ec00e827efebfe8eaa6ed324318ddd7d8870726/src/common/DayGrid.js#L150 Just replace "date.date()" with "date.format('DD')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an option for this in the fullCalendar options curently. Without modifying the fullCalendar source, the best I could come up with is this. If you look at the rendered calendar HTML, you'll see that each day number is wrapped in a `<td>` with the CSS class `fc-day-number`. So we can modify the contents of the `<td>`. Put this code directly after your calendar initialisation code:

```
$('.fc-day-number').each(function() {
  var day = $(this).html(); //get the contents of the td
  //for any fields where the content is one character long, add a leading zero
  if (day.length == 1)
  {
    $(this).html("0" + day);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Years later I could not find an option to set the day-number format to one with a leading zero, i did it the same way but without JavaScript in Fullcalendar 5.4.0:

The classname in my case was `.fc-daygrid-day-number`, I think thats implements the type of the initialized view, whats in my case initialized with: `{initialView: 'dayGridMonth'}`

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.fc-daygrid-day-number'),
    function(el) {
        if (el.innerText.length === 1) {
            el.innerText = '0' + el.innerText;
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with React and find this question equivalent. Then I come up with this solution at Fullcalendar 5.6.0:

I used a prop called "dayCellContent" and passed a function to return the formatted string.

```
<FullCalendar
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
  initialView="dayGridMonth"
  dayCellContent={({ dayNumberText }) => (("00" + dayNumberText).substring(dayNumberText.length))}
/>
```